# having trouble with <pre> <code> on mobile

Tags: html, pre

This issue has been bothing me for a while.

On this site http://www.mikedemar.com/timeline/

I have noticed that the content wraped in the   tags goes outside the white boxes when viewing on mobile devices specifically iPhone.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

- Mike

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CSS like this provide a good base:

```
pre, code, kbd { -moz-tab-size:4; -o-tab-size:4; tab-size:4; }
pre { white-space:pre-wrap; word-wrap:break-word; overflow:auto; }
```

Comment: Thank you!

I adjusted the overflow from auto to none and it worked perfectly.

- Mike